# How to loop through text files in R?

Tags: r, loops

I have three text files . I want to do some calculations as shown below and plot the results.
All text files contain 14 columns X1 to X14 and 601 rows.
This code basically read X3 from all three files and do some computations and then return the result.

```
   ref= read.table("D:\\ref.txt", sep="",header=TRUE)# read first file
   sour1 = read.table("D:\\sour1.txt", sep="",header=TRUE)# read second file
   sour2= read.table("D:\\sour2.txt", sep="",header=TRUE,na.rm=TRUE)# read third file
  result1 = (mean(ref$X3) - ((sd(ref$X3)/sd(sour1$X3))*mean(sour1$X3))+ ((sd(ref$X3)/sd(sour1$X3)*sour1$X3))) # calculate using ref and sour1
result2 = ((mean(ref$X3) - ((sd(ref$X3)/sd(sour2$X3,na.rm=TRUE))*mean(sour2$X3,na.rm=TRUE))+((sd(ref$X3)/sd(sour2$X3,na.rm=TRUE)*sour2$X3))))  # calculate using ref and sour2
plot(ref$X3,result1,ylab="Weight in pounds",xlab="Weight in pounds",col=2)
points(ref$X3,ref$X3, col = 'green')
points(ref$X3,result2, col = 'blue') # from this I get one plot showing 3 variables on y axis against one on x axis.
```

This is only plot using  X3 from all data, but still I have the other columns X1  to X14
My question is how can I do the same thing with all other columns, and finally will get 14 plots.

Comment: You should give some sample of your data not all the files, and simplify the question to include only the part on interest ( applying the function to others columns), otherwise this question is too localized.

Comment: Cuurently your code relies on 2 columns (`X3` and `X1`).  Did you mean that?  (Looping over 2 columns implies different bahviour to looping over 1 column.)

Comment: Sorry I typed wrongly.My  code relies on 1 column: X3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Pop mentioned, you need to create a list of column names and loop over those.

`lapply` provides a lightly more elegant alternative to a `for` loop.

By laying out your code more clearly, you can see that you have some odd double brackets in the lines assigning `result1` and `result2`.  Consider breaking these lines into smaller calculations for clarity.

```
columns <- paste0("X", 1:14)
lapply(
  columns,
  function(column)
  {
    result1 <- (
      mean(ref[[column]]) - 
      ((sd(ref[[column]]) / sd(sour1[[column]])) * mean(sour1[[column]])) + 
      ((sd(ref[[column]]) / sd(sour1[[column]]) * sour1[[column]]))
    )   # calculate using ref and sour1
    result2 <- ((  
      mean(ref[[column]]) - 
      ((sd(ref[[column]]) / sd(sour2[[column]], na.rm=TRUE)) * mean(sour2[[column]], na.rm=TRUE)) + 
      ((sd(ref[[column]]) / sd(sour2[[column]], na.rm=TRUE) * sour2[[column]])) 
    ))  # calculate using ref and sour2
    plot(
      ref[[column]],
      result1,
      ylab = "Weight in pounds",
      xlab = "Weight in pounds",
      col  = 2
    )
    points(ref[[column]], ref[[column]], col = 'green')
    points(ref[[column]], result2, col = 'blue') 
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.But I got this error:`Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf`

Comment: It may mean that there are `NA` or `Inf` in what you plot, therefore you have errors in your calculus or these `NA` values were already in your files.

Comment: Oh yes there are NAs in my data. but I treated them `na.rm=TRUE`.should not be a problem!

Comment: any idea on how to deal with this problems.To get rid of NAs when plotting.

Comment: If your column is all missing and you do `na.rm = TRUE` then you are left with no data. If you pass no data to `max` then it returns `-Inf`.  Try looking at your data with `str`, `summary`, `head`, `View`, etc.

Comment: @Richie Cotton Thanks.I will take care of the NAs. But then the 13 plots will be one over the others so I have to close one to see the others. Is there away to plot them all side by side?

Comment: Combining multiple plots is a separate question.  Take a look at the `ggplot2` package.  If you get stuck try the `lattice` package.  If you are still stuck look at the `layout` function.  If you are still stuck then ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

To get `Xi` for `i` from 1 to 14, you've got to use `paste` function and the alternative way of getting elements in a list : `ref[["X3"]]` instead of `ref$X3`

It gives on your example :

```
for (i in 1:14){
        name <- paste('X',i,sep='')
        result1 = (mean(ref[[name]]) - ((sd(ref[[name]])/sd(sour1[[name]]))*mean(sour1[[name]]))+ ((sd(ref[[name]])/sd(sour1[[name]])*sour1[[name]]))) # calculate using ref and sour1
        result2 = ((mean(ref[[name]]) - ((sd(ref[[name]])/sd(sour2[[name]],na.rm=TRUE))*mean(sour2[[name]],na.rm=TRUE))+((sd(ref[[name]])/sd(sour2[[name]],na.rm=TRUE)*sour2[[name]]))))  # calculate using ref and sour2
        plot(ref[[name]],result1,ylab="Weight in pounds",xlab="Weight in pounds",col=2)
        points(ref[[name]],ref$X1, col = 'green')
        points(ref[[name]],result2, col = 'blue')
}
```